# Running Laravel on VPS server

Tags: php, laravel, vhosts

Hello I installed Laravel on my VPS server, I created a vhost like the following :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.uplink.com
        DocumentRoot var/www/httpdocs/uplink/public

       <Directory var/www/httpdocs/uplink/public>
          <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
          Options -MultiViews
          RewriteEngine On
          RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
         RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
       </IfModule>
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

When I go to mysite.uplink.com it shows : Error in exception handler what I'm doing wrong please? Also I dont know if I should put 80 as the port or an other one.

Thanks

Comment: You need to give 777 permissions to the storage folder and all of the directories within it.

Comment: I hate to do this to you, but do you know what "VPS server" means? ATM machine 4ever!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to give 755 permissions to the storage folder and all of the directories within it.

```
chmod -R 755 /path/to/app/storage
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks working using a url like : http://mysite/uplink/public  but not mysite.uplink.com

Comment: bad idea , give 755 permission

Answer (score 0):

The error has nothing to do with the setting up of your vhost. Your storage folder has not been provided the right permissions.

```
chmod -R 777 /path/to/app/storage
```

Try running this command so that you provide appropriate permissions to the storage folder.

[Question](http://laravel.io/forum/05-01-2014-need-help-with-the-error-error-in-exception-handler) posted on **Laravel.io** with a similar problem

Try the permission section in the **Laravel documentation** about installation [here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/installation#configuration)